# How can I commit only certain modified files that are being tracked in git?

Tags: git

I have several files that are being tracked in my repository, but I want to make a commit that only includes a couple of them, leaving the other files as modified.  Example, suppose I want to make a commit that contains the changes to `c.txt` `d.txt` `e.txt`

```
    modified:   a.txt
    modified:   b.txt
    modified:   c.txt
    modified:   d.txt
    modified:   e.txt
```

Such that my next `git status` yields

```
    modified:   a.txt
    modified:   b.txt
```

There’s gotta be a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Just `git add c.txt d.txt e.txt` and `git commit`.With `git add` you are adding changes to the index, which is by definition the content (excluding metadata) of the next commit.

Comment: You can also pass filenames directly to `git commit`, but this can get unwieldy. Also worth noting is `git add -p`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a commit that contains the changes to c.txt d.txt e.txt

You are misreading the output of `git status` and misunderstanding Git itself.

- Git commits do not contain *changes*. They are snapshots of your *entire* project.
- `git status` tells two different things: what is modified in the working tree (`Changes not staged for commit:`), and what is staged to go into the next commit (`Changes to be committed:`). Both of those list files as `modified` but they are completely different kinds of thing.

You construct Git's understanding what constitutes your project by what you have added to previous commits by way of the index, and (therefore) what is present in the index now. Once you have committed a snapshot containing c.txt, Git is *tracking* c.txt. It is not going to stop tracking it. If you modify c.txt, Git is going to know this and will tell you so in `git status`, under `Changes not staged for commit:`.

But that does not mean that Git is going to *commit* the current state of c.txt the next time you make a commit. Git will only do that if you *add* the current state of c.txt to the index. If you don't add it, Git won't commit it. If you *have* added it, so that it appears under `Changes to be committed:`, and you wish you hadn't, use `git restore`, as `git status` tells you to do.

Comment: And may I recommend my intro tutorial https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ which goes into even more detail about how to read `git status` output.